# How to write a UDTF when the table structure is not known in advance

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, udtf

I want to write a "utility" User Defined Function that will run some SQL, using the values passed in as parameters, and returns the resultset as a table. Based on the parameter values passed in, the query could return any number of columns.

From what I can see, in a UDTF the columns in the table being returned have to be defined at the point the function is created e.g. something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION t()
RETURNS TABLE(msg VARCHAR) ...
```

Declaring the function as just a table but without listing the columns throws an error e.g. this won't work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION t()
    RETURNS TABLE() ...
```

Can anyone think of a way of getting this to work, given that the end result must a table function that can be embedded in a SQL statement? For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(MY_FUNCTION(param1));
```

Is there another approach that would work e.g. my function returns data in a structure other than a table (e.g. JSON) and there are out-of-the-box Snowflake functions that could turn it into a table (without knowing the structure of the table in advance). For example,

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(SF_FUNCTION(MY_FUNCTION(param1)));
```

Everything I have tried has, at some point, run into the issue of having to know the table structure in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the case of unknown/variable input arguments, you can compose them into an array or object type using (`array`|`object`)`_construct(*)` or similar functions, and then extract the arguments programmatically within your function as needed.

Likewise, returning an unknown number of columns from the function is best handled by returning array or object column(s) and then post processing it to further extract and columnarise it if needed.

[This recent Medium blog](https://medium.com/snowflake/defining-snowpark-udtfs-without-specifying-input-or-output-columns-9ee7805813b6) shows how to do this for Python based UDTFs.

Note, you might also benefit from a performance perspective by using the new [Vectorized Python UDTF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-tabular-vectorized), which is more efficient when passing and processing table-like operations in your function.

---

< Added to respond to NickW's comment re how to post-process UDTF output to columns >

There's no way within a queries `FROM` clause to expand array/object columns into columnarised tabular output.

One possible solution is to use a Stored Procedure to convert it. Although UDFs don't support returning undefined columns as output, SQL and Python Stored Procedures do.

The Python Stored Procedure below is adapted from the code in the blog I linked earlier.  It can be used to convert a UDTF `OBJECT` output column into a columnarised row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE columnarise_object_row_py(query_id STRING, object_name STRING)
RETURNS TABLE()  -- <-- note that a Stored Procedure can be defined without explicit output columns
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.9'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'run'
COMMENT = 'Dynamically columnarise object_row table with Python Sproc'
EXECUTE AS CALLER  -- Note: Need this for the CALL to use the QUERY-ID from the calling session
AS
$$
from snowflake.snowpark import functions as F
from snowflake.snowpark import types as T
import json

def run(session, query_id, object_name):
  # Create a dataframe from the supplied query-id, and name of the object-column representing the tabular data
  results_df = session.sql(f'''select {object_name} OBJECT_ROW from table(result_scan(\'{query_id}\'))''')
  # Flatten
  results_df_flat = results_df.join_table_function("flatten", F.col("OBJECT_ROW"))
  # Get the distinct keys that exist in the return row OBJECTs.  
  ### If this is the same for each row a LIMIT clause can be used to speed up this query
  keylist = [row["KEY"] for row in results_df_flat.select("KEY").distinct().collect()]      
  # Pivot
  results_df_pivot = (
      results_df_flat.select("SEQ", "KEY", "VALUE")
      .pivot("KEY", keylist)
      .max("VALUE")
      .drop("SEQ")
  )
  # Get types for the columns as a dict
  results_col_types = json.loads(session.sql(f'''with t_1 as (select * from table(result_scan('{query_id}')) limit 1)
        select 
        object_agg(key,
                   iff(typeof(value) = \'DECIMAL\', \'FLOAT\', typeof(value))::variant
                   ) type_dict 
        from t_1, lateral flatten(input => {object_name}) ''').collect()[0][0])
  # rename columns to remove "" from the pivot      
  results_df_pivot_renamed = results_df_pivot.select(
      [F.col(col_nm).alias(col_nm[2:-2]) for col_nm in results_df_pivot.columns])
  # re-type the results based on the col types returned from typeof()    
  results_df_pivot_typed = results_df_pivot_renamed.select(
      [F.sql_expr(f'''{col_nm}::{results_col_types[col_nm]} {col_nm}''') for col_nm in results_df_pivot_renamed.columns])
  # Return the tabular result    
  return results_df_pivot_typed
$$;
```

Let's use this to convert the output of our UDTF, assuming we have packaged the rows into `OBJECT`'s. Create some test data:

```
create or replace table numbers as
select 
  digit_int,
  digit_dec::Decimal(10,2) digit_dec,
  digit_dec::Float digit_float,
  alpha,
  roman,
  even,
  array_construct(digit_int) digit_array,
  object_construct(upper(alpha),digit_int) alpha_digit_object
from 
(values 
   (1, 1.1, 'one', 'i', False),
   (2, 2.2, 'two', 'ii', True),
   (3, 3.3, 'three', 'iii', False),
   (4, 4.4, 'four', 'iv', True),
   (5, 5.5, 'five', 'v', False)
    ) as numerals (digit_int, digit_dec, alpha, roman, even)
;
```

For testing this query serves as a proxy for your UDTF that returns its output as an `OBJECT` per row.

```
select object_construct_keep_null(*) my_udtf_output_col
  from (select * from numbers);
```

[image]

And then call the Stored Procedure which returns the columnarised tabular result:

```
call columnarise_object_row_py(LAST_QUERY_ID(), 'MY_UDTF_OUTPUT_COL');
```

[image]

If you want to make use of the tabular result, for example to create a table from it you can do:

```
create table my_columnarised_output as
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response and apologies if I’ve missed something in your answer/links but I think the issue is with your statement “… and then post processing it to further extract and columnarise it if needed” - that’s the issue I’m facing, how to do this so that it returns a table structure that can be embedded in the FROM part of a SELECT statement